# the time of appearance of objects i am using opencv and YOLO python

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

i'm using python opencv with yolo to detect person in waiting room,i want to know how much time people spend in the waiting room .
my code to detect person work but I don't know how to calculate the time of appearance of persons

time is calculated for each person who appears in the webcam and as soon as the person disappears the time stops for this person and sends his time back to the waiting room

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np



#Write down conf, nms thresholds,inp width/height
confThreshold = 0.25
nmsThreshold = 0.40
inpWidth = 416
inpHeight = 416


#Load names of classes and turn that into a list
classesFile = "coco.names"
classes = None

with open(classesFile,'rt') as f:
    classes = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

#Model configuration
modelConf = 'yolov3.cfg'
modelWeights = 'yolov3.weights'

def postprocess(frame, outs):

    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]

    classIDs = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []




    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:

            scores = detection [5:]
            classID = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classID]

            if confidence > confThreshold:
                centerX = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                centerY = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)

                width = int(detection[2]* frameWidth)
                height = int(detection[3]*frameHeight )

                left = int(centerX - width/2)
                top = int(centerY - height/2)

                classIDs.append(classID)
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                boxes.append([left, top, width, height])

    indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes (boxes,confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold )

    indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes[i]
        left = box[0]
        top = box[1]
        width = box[2]
        height = box[3]
        if classIDs[i] == 0 :
            drawPred(classIDs[i], confidences[i], left, top, left + width, top + height)


def drawPred(classId, conf, left, top, right, bottom):
    # Draw a bounding box.

    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 178, 50), 3)

    label = '%.2f' % conf

    # Get the label for the class name and its confidence
    if classes:
        assert (classId < len(classes))
        label = '%s:%s' % (classes[classId],label)




    #A fancier display of the label from learnopencv.com 
    # Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    #labelSize, baseLine = cv.getTextSize(label, cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
    #top = max(top, labelSize[1])
    #cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top - round(1.5 * labelSize[1])), (left + round(1.5 * labelSize[0]), top + baseLine),
                 #(255, 255, 255), cv.FILLED)
    # cv.rectangle(frame, (left,top),(right,bottom), (255,255,255), 1 )
    #cv.putText(frame, label, (left, top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 0, 0), 1)
    cv.putText(frame, label, (left,top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)

def getOutputsNames(net):
    # Get the names of all the layers in the network
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()

    # Get the names of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


#Set up the net

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConf, modelWeights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)


#Process inputs
winName = 'DL OD with OpenCV'
cv.namedWindow(winName, cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow(winName, 1000,1000)





cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)


while cv.waitKey(1) < 0:

    #get frame from video
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()

    #Create a 4D blob from a frame

    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1/255, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop = False)

    #Set the input the the net
    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward (getOutputsNames(net))


    postprocess (frame, outs)

    #show the image
    cv.imshow(winName, frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question, if I understand it correctly, is about computing elapsed time in Python. This has nothing to do with OpenCV nor YOLO and can be achieve with :

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
# one eternity later
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Then you start the timer when a new person arrives in the room and you stop it when it leaves.

According to the code you just add, you need to track the objects. Detecting them is not enough to compute their age.

By tracking I mean you need to know if an object is new or if it has been present in the past frame.

Once you have identified all the objects you can increment a time counter.
When they disappear, you read the counter to get how long they stayed.

Tracking is a huge subject and can't be sum up in a SO thread I think.
Moreover there is no magical solution, you can use several different algorithms and the results depends on your video input.

## Simple algorithm

A simple approche is to compare the position of the found objects between frame. For example, at frame 0 you have one object at position p0, you call it 'A'.

On the next frame, you hava two objects, you compute the distance between them and p0. If one is close enough (below a threshold you should determine) then you can consider it is your object A. Then you can increase its age. And call the second one B.

Then go to the next frame. If there is no object close enough to last position of object A on this frame, you can consider A disappear and get its age.

Comment: i know but I want to calculate the time of each person who appeared in the camera

Comment: then you might be more precise and post some code snippet so people can have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: how i know when the object was remove